# inlineNav Edit button not working with multiselect jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

i have multiselect inline editable jqGrid with `inlineNav`. following step are created problem:

1. click on add button,empty record get display in grid.add data and save it.
2. select that record using checkbox.
3. add one more record in grid as per 1 step,but click on cancel button insteat of save it.
4. recent record get disappered,click on edit button as i already selected one record.
5. selected record doesn't come in edit mode,it is giving warning message "select row".
6. if i deselect and select once again and click on edit button then it will appear in edit mode.

can you please tell me any solution?

```
var i = 1;
var lastSelection = 0;
$(function () {
    $("#curruntppeGridgrid").jqGrid({
        url: 'getcostperformancecurreuntPPE',
        datatype: "json",
        jsonReader: { "repeatitems": false, unformat: Unformat_Select },
        colNames: ['Category', 'Manufacturer', 'Style', 'UOM', 'Count', 'Unit', 'Qty', 'Cost', 'Sizes', 'Annual Cost', 'VP2'],
        colModel: [
            {
                name: 'category', index: 'category', align: 'center', editable: true, hidden: false, edittype: 'select',
                editoptions: {
                    multiple: false, value: catList,
                    dataEvents: [{
                        type: 'change',
                        fn: function (e) {
                            loadStyle(e);
                        }
                    }]
                },
                editrules: { required: false, custom: true, custom_func: categorycheck }
            },
            {
                name: 'manufacturer', index: 'manufacturer', align: 'center', editable: true, hidden: false, edittype: 'select',
                editoptions: {
                    value: manufList,
                    dataEvents: [{
                        type: 'change',
                        fn: function (e) {
                            loadStyle(e);
                        }
                    }]
                },
                editrules: { required: false }
            },
            {
                name: 'style', index: 'style', align: 'center', editable: true, hidden: false, edittype: 'select',
                editoptions: {
                    multiple: false, value: styleList,
                    dataInit: function (elem) {
                        var v = $(elem).val();
                        if (v != '') {
                            var data = loadSizes(elem);
                            jQuery('#curruntppeGridgrid').setColProp('sizes', { editoptions: { multiple: true, value: data } });
                            var data1 = loadUom(elem);
                            jQuery('#curruntppeGridgrid').setColProp('uom', { editoptions: { value: data1 } });
                        }
                        else {
                            jQuery('#curruntppeGridgrid').setColProp('sizes', { editoptions: { multiple: true, value: {} } });
                            jQuery('#curruntppeGridgrid').setColProp('uom', { editoptions: { value: {} } });
                        }
                    },
                    dataEvents: [{
                        type: 'change',
                        fn: function (e) {
                            loadCategoryAndManufacturer(e);
                        }
                    }]

                },
                editrules: { required: true }
            },
            {
                name: 'uom', index: 'uom', align: 'center', editable: true, hidden: false, edittype: 'select',
                editoptions: {
                    multiple: false, value: uomfList,
                    dataEvents: [{
                        type: 'change',
                        fn: function (e) {
                            setHiddenUom(e);
                        }
                    }]
                },
                editrules: { required: false }
            },
            {
                name: 'averagelifetime', index: 'averagelifetime', editable: true, align: 'center', sortable: false, editrules: { number: true, maxValue: 9999999.99 },
                editoptions: {
                    class: 'validate[custom[number]]',
                    dataEvents: [{
                        type: 'click',
                        fn: function (e) {
                            $('#formQuickSurvey').validationEngine({ promptPosition: 'bottomLeft', validationEventTrigger: 'keyup' });
                        }
                    },
                                {
                                    type: 'change',
                                    fn: function (e) {
                                        setQty(e);
                                    }
                                }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'averagelifetimeselect', index: 'averagelifetimeselect', editable: true, align: 'center', edittype: 'select',
                editoptions: {
                    multiple: false, value: avglifetimelist,
                    dataInit: function (elem) {
                        var v = $(elem).val();
                        if (v != '') {
                            jQuery('#curruntppeGridgrid').setColProp('averagelifetimeselectId', { editoptions: { defaultValue: v } });
                        }
                    },
                    dataEvents: [{
                        type: 'change',
                        fn: function (e) {
                            setHiddenaveragelifetimeselect(e);
                            setQty(e);
                        }
                    }]
                },
                editrules: { required: false }
            },
            {
                name: 'qty', index: 'qty', align: 'center', editable: true, editrules: { integer: true, maxValue: 2147483647 },
                editoptions: {
                    class: 'validate[custom[numbersOnly]]',
                    dataEvents: [{
                        type: 'change',
                        fn: function (e) {
                            calculateannualCost(e);
                        }
                    }, {
                        type: 'click',
                        fn: function (e) {
                            $('#formQuickSurvey').validationEngine({ promptPosition: 'bottomLeft', validationEventTrigger: 'keyup' });
                        }
                    }]
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'cost', index: 'cost', align: 'center', editable: true, editrules: { number: true, maxValue: 9999999.99 },
                editoptions: {
                    class: 'validate[custom[number]]',
                    dataEvents: [{
                        type: 'change',
                        fn: function (e) {
                            calculateannualCost(e);
                        }
                    }, {
                        type: 'click',
                        fn: function (e) {
                            $('#formQuickSurvey').validationEngine({ promptPosition: 'bottomLeft', validationEventTrigger: 'keyup' });
                        }
                    }]
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'sizes', index: 'sizes', align: 'center', edittype: 'select', classes: 'seteventclickoncurrent', editable: true, editoptions: {
                    multiple: true, value: {},
                    dataInit: function (elem) {
                        var v = $(elem).val();
                        if (v != '') {
                            jQuery('#curruntppeGridgrid').setColProp('sizesId', { editoptions: { defaultValue: v } });
                        }
                    },
                    dataEvents: [{
                        type: 'change',
                        fn: function (e) {
                            setHiddensizes(e);
                        }
                    }]
                },
                editrules: { required: false, custom: true, custom_func: checkCurrentSize }
            },
            { name: 'annualCost', index: 'annualCost', align: 'center', editable: true, editoptions: { readonly: 'readonly' } },
            {
                name: 'vp2', index: 'vp2', align: 'center', editable: true, hidden: false, edittype: 'select',
                editoptions: {
                    multiple: false, value: vp2fList,
                    dataInit: function (elem) {
                        var v = $(elem).val();
                        if (v != '') {
                            jQuery('#curruntppeGridgrid').setColProp('vp2Id', { editoptions: { defaultValue: v } });
                        }
                    },
                    dataEvents: [{
                        type: 'change',
                        fn: function (e) {
                            setHiddenvp2(e);
                            validateCategoryandVP2(e);
                        }
                    }]
                },
                editrules: { required: false }
            }
        ],
        cmTemplate: { sortable: false },
        width: eval('gridWidth()'),
        pgbuttons: false,
        pginput: false,
        viewrecords: false,
        //pager: '#curruntppeGridpager',
        toppager: true,
        multiselect: true,
        editurl: 'editsurveyppe',
        caption: 'Current PPE',
        //forceFit:true,
        hiddengrid: true,
        hidegrid: true,
        headertitles: true,
        postData: {
            appId: function () { return $('#selectApplication option:selected').val(); }
        },
        loadComplete: function () {
            $('#del_curruntppeGridgrid_top').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');//this is added to enable delete button after record reload
            if (jQuery('#curruntppeGridgrid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'gridstate') != 'visible') {
                $("#curruntppeGridgrid_toppager").hide();
            }
            else {
                $("#curruntppeGridgrid_toppager").show();
            }
        },
        afterInsertRow: function () {//this is added to disable delete button while adding record
            $('#del_curruntppeGridgrid_top').addClass('ui-state-disabled');

        }, ajaxSelectOptions: { cache: false }
    });

    jQuery("#curruntppeGridgrid").jqGrid('navGrid', "#curruntppeGridpager",
        { cloneToTop: true, position: 'right', edit: false, add: false, del: true, search: false, refresh: false, pgbuttons: false },
        {}, {}, {
            mtype: 'POST', reloadAfterSubmit: true,
            serializeDelData: function (postdata) {
                var row = jQuery('#curruntppeGridgrid').getRowData(postdata.id);
                // append postdata with extra information
                return { id: postdata.id, oper: postdata.oper, gridId: 'current' };
            }
        }, {});

    //top toolbar
    jQuery("#curruntppeGridgrid").jqGrid('inlineNav', '#curruntppeGridgrid_toppager', {
        position: 'right',
        editParams: {
            aftersavefunc: function () {
                $("#curruntppeGridgrid").jqGrid().trigger("reloadGrid");
                $('#del_curruntppeGridgrid_top').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');//this is added to enable delete button after saveing record
            }, oneditfunc: function () {
                $('#del_curruntppeGridgrid_top').addClass('ui-state-disabled');//this is added to disable delete button while editing record
            }, afterrestorefunc: function () {
                $('#del_curruntppeGridgrid_top').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');//this is added to enable delete button while cancelling record
            }, extraparam: {
                currentApplicationId: function () { return $("#selectApplication option:selected").val(); }
            }
        },
        "restoreAfterSelect": false
    });

    jQuery('#curruntppeGridgrid').jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
        useColSpanStyle: true,
        groupHeaders: [{
            startColumnName: 'averagelifetime',
            numberOfColumns: 2,
            titleText: '<em>Average Lifetime</em>'
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a bug in jqGrid. I posted my suggestions how to fix the problem in [the following bug report](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/setting-selrow-to-null-inside-of-delrowdata-in-case-multiselecttrue-and-selarrrow-length-0/#p27675). I suggest to modify [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.base.js#L2834) of code of `delRowData`

```js
if(rowid == $t.p.selrow) {$t.p.selrow=null;}
```

to the following code

```js
if(rowid == $t.p.selrow) {
    if ($t.p.multiselect && $t.p.selarrrow.length > 0) {
        $t.p.selrow = $t.p.selarrrow[$t.p.selarrrow.length-1];
    } else {
        $t.p.selrow = null;
    }
}
```

You can find the modified version of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.1/js/jquery.jqGrid.src-addUniqueRowid.js). The code includes some additional small improvements in the code of `addRow`. I described the improvements in [the next bug report](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/duplicate-rowid-produced-by-addrow/#p27676) which I posted to trirand.

**UPDATED**: The bug is already fixed (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/dd452fa490bcf6437955b63b1188b4d15f2cb828)) in the main code of jqGrid which one can find on the [github](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid). So the fix will be in the next (higher as 4.4.1) version of jqGrid.

Comment: Thank you so much Oleg. It’s working, with this you made my life so easier.